# Best Approach to Present Modals After App Reaches Foreground

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, modalviewcontroller

Users within my iOS application have two states, logged in and logged out. I am using firebase sdk for auth and realtime database data delivery.

For logged in users, I want to present custom in-app alert modals if a certain condition is true for that alert. These conditions are date-drive, i.e. users will get a specific alert on certain dates, but not others. This means the conditions are not decided from user input.

When the server returns that the conditions are met for a certain alert, there are different states. These are what I can think of:

- Users can open the app from a killed state where the auth is
  reestablished during the app's initialization, i.e. logged
  out->logged in.
- Users can open the app from a background state.
- Users can be in-app while the date changes.

My question is what is best practice here? The three approaches (maybe neither are best) I am considering are these:

1. Singleton - Have an AlertManager singleton that listens for the alert conditions met events and then the singleton navigates the view controller tree to find the current foreground view controller to present the alert
2. Protocol - Have a protocol that is adopted by all view controllers. Not entirely sure how I would go about this one as I cannot override the viewDidAppear method from a Protocol default implementation. Not sure if this approach is viable for that reason.
3. Inheritance - Have a ViewController base class that is inherited by all custom View Controllers. That base class handles alert checks in its viewDidAppear method.

A tangential question to consider is how I should be handling the case when there is already a presented view controller when I need to present the alert view controller? I do not want to interrupt the user so I would want to queue the alert to be presented after the currently presented view controller is dismissed.

Comment: are you changing the first responder in the AppDelegate ? when user return to application to check on isLogged or not ?

Comment: not to my knowledge, no. I have a singleton AuthManager that listens for auth state change events and updates the application/rootViewController accordingly.

Comment: so you are trying to change the scene ? when user logged in or not ? and based on that you want to present a View

Comment: If a user is logged in and alert conditions are met, they should be presented with a modal. If a user is logged out, they should never be presented with a modal regardless of conditions. If a user changes state from logged out to logged in, a modal should be presented if conditions are met.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function in `AppDelegate.swift`

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:
        [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
```

An example for your case

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:
    [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    //Check if User logged in 
    if logged 
    {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let initialViewController = 
        storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourLoggedinVC")
        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    } else {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let initialViewController = 
        storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourLoggedOutVC")
        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

}

Comment: This only covers the case where the app is launched from an unInitialized/killed state. Additionally, I am not concerned with reestablishing the key window's rootViewController, but rather modally presenting an alert view controller on top of the existing key window's root view controller's topmost view controller.